# Image below UISearchBar like Notes app - iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uisearchbar

The Notes app uses a small image of ragged paper to imply prior torn pages.
I tried to replicate this behaviour in the following way, but my problem is, the search bar doesn't become active anymore.

```
//mySearchBar and raggedPaper are instance variables

mySearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,44)];
mySearchBar.delegate = self;
[mySearchBar sizeToFit];

raggedPaper = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"raggedpaper.png"]];

[raggedPaper addSubView:mySearchBar];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = raggedPaper;
```

Everything looks alright, but the searchbar doesn't activate anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this :

```
raggedPaper.userInteractionEnabled = YES
```

Or if it doesn't work, you can do the other way around : add the ragged paper image to the search bar, whose clipsToBounds is set to NO.

Comment: userInteractionEnabled works! And it sounds so logically, thank you.